# Rendering static content in Symfony2 project

Tags: symfony

I would like to include static content in a Symfony2 project. I have auto-generated some documentation HTML files that I would like to render. They are complete HTML files, with links between them.

Thus, I would have something like:

- `mysite.com`: Routing managed by Symfony2, using its MVC engine.
- `mysite.com/docs/`, `mysite.com/docs/.../.../`, etc : Just return the content of those HTML static files.

I guess I would need to create a bundle that deals with these static files, stored in its `Resources/public`, but I don't know what is the best way to achieve this. Also, the routing should be able to recognize every route under `mysite.com/docs/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the directory `docs` in the `web` directory.

If you look at the rewrite rule in the `.htaccess` located in the `web` directory you will see :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It means "if the file doesn't exists, use the app.php (therefore Symfony2) file with the rewrite rule".

Thus, if you create the file (e.g `docs/test.html`) in the web directory, you will be able to access it directly `from mysite.com/docs/test.html`

**Edit** :
Think about the `css` and `js` files for examples. When you include them, they are not handle by the router